# Selecting datetime from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date, vb6

I'm selecting a date from SQL Server, but having an issue. If I inserted the data as `06/06/2012`, it gets saved in this format in SQL Server. When I SELECT it from the table, it looks like `6/6/2012`.

I tried to use this:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, LastName, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DOB, 101)
FROM 
    TblClients
```

but I get an error:

> ITEM cannot be found in the collection corresponding to this name or ordinal.

Comment: Remove the comma after SELECT.

Comment: Sounds like it's already `varchar` if it inserted as `06/06/2012`.  Can you verify whether the column is `varchar` or `datetime`?

Comment: it's datetime, just checked in design

Comment: If you don't have a comma after the `SELECT`, can you edit your question and remove it.  If you do then (as mentioned by @BWS) that's the problem.

Comment: edited it already, my apologies. I was just copying and pasting stuff did not notice

Comment: also used (datetime,dob,101) still giving me the same error

Comment: That looks like a vb error message as opposed to a SQL Server error message. How are you trying to access the data?

Comment: I select the data for about 12 fields. For every field I am able to pull the correct data. The problem I see is with the formatting of Date of Birth. When i use convert, it gives me the error. I even went as far as creating a new variable dateOfBirth as date, then right after opening the recordset I formatted it like this dateOfBirth = format(g_RS("DOB"),"MM/DD/YYYY" )and it still only shows as 6/6/2012

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do is compare the value from tblClients and value from a mskDOB.text. So what I did is I converted both to string, formatted them in this way--> "YYYYMMDD", compared them and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your VB code is fine until you don't return the expected "ITEM".

Try aliasing your `convert` with the column name:
`SELECT FirstName, LastName, convert(varchar,DOB, 101) AS DOB From TblClients`

Comment: Yeah this was returning an error. I found the way to do this. What I needed to do is compare the value from tblClients and value from a mskDOB.text. So what I did is I converted both to string "YYYYMMDD", compared them and it works. Thanks all for your input.

Comment: Great!  I'm glad you found a solution.